# Open quickfix in current vertical split

Tags: quickfix

I usually use a layout of one vertical split and two different buffers. When i use `:copen`, the quickfix window always opens in the right split, regardless where my cursor is. Consequently, if my cursor is in the left split, and I issue the commands `:copen`, `:cclose`, the buffer is changed.

Is there any way of opening the quickfix window in the same vertical split where my cursor is?

Comment: I'm not sure you can easily make it open in the current split but you could use `:botright copen` to make the window occupy the full width.

Comment: @Isund The quickfix window has the special filetype `qf` so you could also use an autocommand like `autocmd! FileType qf Myfunction()` using a function which puts the window where you want.